# Connecting Form Dropdown to Backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a feature to a web application where users can rate courses. Within the rating feature, there is a pre-set list of instructors that taught each course. This is stored within a postgres db as an array.

The course model (which the list of instructors is part of) and the review model are separate.

I have successfully created a form which shows the list of instructors as a dropdown when writing a review, but I have been unsuccessful in saving the name of the instructor in the column for the database.

I am unsure what to put in the last line for the following code for the data to save.

reviews_controller.rb

```
def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.course_id = @course.id
    @review.instructor_name =
```

This is how I have displayed it in the front-end to allow users to select the instructors.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form.label "Instructor" %>
<%= select_tag :instructor_name, options_for_select(@course.instructors) %>
```

I am expecting the name of the instructor selected to be saved in the database as opposed to the value as opposed to the index of the name.

Comment: What's the output HTML for the select options? Is it something like `<option value="1">John Doe</option>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= select_tag :instructor_name, options_for_select(@course.instructors.collect { |i| [i, i] }) %>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work, unfortunately. I'm getting undefined method `name' for "Robert Romeo":String

Comment: I have changed the answer. Please try again

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form you will receive the name of the instructor in the params. In the controller you can access the params and add it to the review.

reviews_controller.rb

```
def create    
  @review = Review.new(review_params)
  @review.user_id = current_user.id
  @review.course_id = @course.id
  @review.instructor_name = params[:instructor_name]
end
```